# Linking static lib (potracelib) with another lib, what to write in Makefile.am?

Tags: c, makefile, autotools, automake

**I need to link libpotrace and compile it into libgerbv. What should I write in Makefile.am? I tried various things like LDADD, LIBDIR, LDFLAGS etc., but I was not successful.**

How my structure look like:

- gerbv/gerbv-test -> files from git, master brach
- gerbv/libs/potrace/potrace-test -> potrace -> files from sourceforge.com, latest release

I use Debian Jessie, I can compile both programs separately, both I did not figured out, how can I link potrace to gerbv and compile it. The header file (.h) is included properly, but I haven't had any success with linking .so or .a/la lib. Even no success with installed potrace in /usr/local/lib or /usr/lib.

**Can anyone direct me? The best will be if you can download both programs, compile it without error and then write what you put into the gerbv/src/makefile.Am.**



**UPDATED**

I dowloaded clean releases and did this ONLY this modifies:

- /root/NBP/gerbv/gerbv-test/src/Makefile.am

added

```
libgerbv_la_LIBADD = libpotrace.la # src/Makefile.am:84: error: use 'libgerbv_la_LIBADD', not 'libgerbv_la_LDADD'
libgerbv_la_LIBDIR = /root/NBP/gerbv/libs/potrace/potrace-old/src/.libs
#libgerbv_la_DEPENDENCIES = libpotrace.la
```

- /root/NBP/gerbv/gerbv-test/src/exportimage.c

added at the top

```
#include "../../libs/potrace/potrace-test/src/potracelib.h"
```

added into void exportimage_render_to_surface_and_destroy(...), this will test, if the shared lib is properly linked. exportimage.c is part of libgerbv where I need to include libpotrace.

```
char *v = potrace_version();
```

After doing this modifications I build it via:

- libpotrace

```
root:~/NBP/gerbv/libs/potrace/potrace-test# autoreconf && ./configure --with-libpotrace && make
```

runs without a problem...

- gerbv/libgerbv

```
root:~/NBP/gerbv/gerbv-test# autoreconf && ./configure && make
```

This results with:

```
...
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/NBP/gerbv/gerbv-test/src'
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'libpotrace.la', needed by 'libgerbv.la'.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/NBP/gerbv/gerbv-test/src'
Makefile:498: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/NBP/gerbv/gerbv-test/src'
Makefile:472: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/NBP/gerbv/gerbv-test'
Makefile:401: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: hi can you post `makefile.am`  here? use `-L` to include path and `-l` for link library.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Q0QC2DRD Makefile.am from /root/NBP/gerbv/gerbv-test/src/Makefile.am , edited as above (lines 84 - 86)

Comment: autoreconf && ./configure && make -L/root/NBP/gerbv/libs/potrace/potrace-test/src/.libs -lpotrace gives me make: invalid option -- '/'

Comment: I zipped the all files, see http://uloz.to/xXvfvtYX/gerbv-zip . Simply unzip it to /root/NBP/ . Any direction how to link it will help me a lot.

Comment: Is this about C or C++? Please pick one and don't spam random tags.

Comment: I removed the C++ flag, both program/libs are in C and this question is mainly about makefile. I already solved it myself and put the answer below,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this Makefile.am addition:

```
libgerbv_la_LIBADD = ../../libs/potrace/potrace/src/libpotrace.la
libgerbv_la_DEPENDENCIES  = ../../libs/potrace/potrace/src/libpotrace.la
```